# Variant of defaultdict for assigning value only once

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary of words with words hashed to an integer for further processing. Is there a variant of `defaultdict` that i can use to avoid the check `if word not in wordid`. This is a very large file and need time efficient way of doing this.

```
 wordid=defaultdict(int)
 totaluniquewords = 0
 for word in sentencewords:
    if word not in wordid:
        totaluniquewords+=1
        wordid[word]=totaluniquewords
```

Comment: Why are you doing it like that anyway?! Why not just `wordid[word] += 1`? Or use a `Counter`!

Comment: I am not counting the no of occurences. I am assigning integers to words to uniquely identify the words

Comment: Oh... then why not just put the words into a set, cast it to a list afterwards and use the index? For example: `dict(enumerate(set(sentencewords)))`? This will give you one integer for each unique word, and you can easily reverse the dictionary if needed (`{v: k for k, v in d.items()}`) as the values are unique too. I don't think `defaultdict` is right for this at all.

Comment: And this is not just one sentence. This is a stream of sentences like in millions

Comment: So? Membership testing in a `[default]dict` or `set` is `O(1)`, because of the underlying hash table implementation, so I don't think `word not in wordid` is a bottleneck anyway.

Comment: So, whatever already I have done must not be a bottleneck for the runtime?

Comment: It seems unlikely, `thing in dictionary` is pretty performant. Have you actually tried doing some profiling? Iterating over that many words is probably going to be slow however you do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: indexing a list with unique index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313761/python-indexing-a-list-with-unique-index)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler and faster way to get what you want:

```
from itertools import count

wordid = dict(zip(set(sentencewords), count(1)))
```

This uses a `set` to obtain the *unique* words in `sentencewords`, pairs each of those unique words with the next value from `count()` (which counts upwards), and constructs a dictionary from the results.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a variant of `defaultdict` that i can use to avoid the check `if word not in wordid`?

Yes, just pass `itertools.count().__next__` to its constructor:
<sup>`itertools.count().next` in Python2</sup>

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import count
>>> dct = defaultdict(count().__next__)
>>> dct['anything']
0
>>> dct['test']
1
```

## Explanation

1. `defaultdict`'s first parameter is callable. When you try to get nonexistent key, it calls this callable without arguments and returns the result. The result is also stored in the defaultdict – when you try to get that item again, it already exist, and you get the same value as before.
2. `itertools.count()` returns iterator that counts from 0 to infinity.
3. `__next__` is iterator's method that obtains next element from iterator.

So, basicly, `itertools.count().__next__` is callable that returns next natural number each time it's called.

Comment: That's neat, but could use an explanation

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It's self-explanatory for me, I don't have any idea what explanation I could add.

Comment: What `count` does? What `__next__` does? What the outcome of using it as the argument to `defaultdict` is? That it won't work at all in 2.x? A code dump on its own, whether or not it works, is rarely a high quality answer.