# Indexing a list with an unique index

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list say `l = [10,10,20,15,10,20]`. I want to assign each unique value a certain "index" to get `[1,1,2,3,1,2]`.

This is my code:

```
a = list(set(l))
res = [a.index(x) for x in l]
```

Which turns out to be very slow.

`l` has 1M elements, and 100K unique elements. I have also tried map with lambda and sorting, which did not help. What is the ideal way to do this?

Comment: Do you care about space complexity or only time complexity?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The slowness of your code arises because `a.index(x)` performs a linear search and you perform that linear search for each of the elements in `l`.  So for each of the 1M items you perform (up to) 100K comparisons.

The fastest way to transform one value to another is looking it up in a map.  You'll need to create the map and fill in the relationship between the original values and the values you want.  Then retrieve the value from the map when you encounter another of the same value in your list.

Here is an example that makes a single pass through `l`.  There may be room for further optimization to eliminate the need to repeatedly reallocate `res` when appending to it.

```
res = []
conversion = {}
i = 0
for x in l:
    if x not in conversion:
        value = conversion[x] = i
        i += 1
    else:
        value = conversion[x]
    res.append(value)
```

Comment: This is how I would do it. I believe this answer will be the easiest for OP to understand. Couple questions if I may, lets say we have 1b records, 1m unique, then the size of `conversion` would be 1m, is there a way for us to reduce that? also how would you optimize `res` append operation

Comment: `for each of the 1M items you perform (up to) 100K comparisons` — why 100K? It should be 1M x 1M, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So with your code I am able to get a dictionary, in which neither keys and values have duplicated number. By using a inversed dictionary `inv_map = {v: k for k, v in conversion.items()}` I can get the original values with index values.

Comment: @eugeney Since `a = list(set(l))`, `len(a)` will be 100K. The conversion to a set reduces the size to just the unique values.

Comment: @taesu `res` could be created large enough, eg `res = [None] * len(l)`. Then you would need to track the index through the loop and replace the placeholder *None* values with the desired number. This will avoid the malloc and memcpy that occur within append() when the underlying array's capacity is exceeded.

Answer (score 38):

You can do this in `O(N)` time using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and a list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lst = [10, 10, 20, 15, 10, 20]
>>> d = defaultdict(count(1).next)
>>> [d[k] for k in lst]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

In Python 3 use [`__next__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) instead of [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next).

---

**If you're wondering how it works?**

The `default_factory`(i.e `count(1).next` in this case) passed to `defaultdict` is called only when Python encounters a missing key, so for 10 the value is going to be 1, then for the next ten it is not a missing key anymore hence the previously calculated 1 is used, now 20 is again a missing key and Python will call the `default_factory` again to get its value and so on.

`d` at the end will look like this:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<method-wrapper 'next' of itertools.count object at 0x1057c83b0>,
            {10: 1, 20: 2, 15: 3})
```

Answer (score 7):

Well I guess it depends on if you want it to return the indexes in that specific order or not. If you want the example to return:

```
    [1,1,2,3,1,2]
```

then you can look at the other answers submitted. However if you only care about getting a unique index for each unique number then I have a fast solution for you

```
    import numpy as np
    l = [10,10,20,15,10,20]
    a = np.array(l)
    x,y = np.unique(a,return_inverse = True)
```

and for this example the output of y is:

```
    y = [0,0,2,1,0,2]
```

I tested this for 1,000,000 entries and it was done essentially immediately.

Comment: It requires numpy, which is a pretty big dependency for such a task. And it will obviously be fast due to the fact that numpy implements its algorithms in C or Fortran.

Comment: the question asked for the fastest way, but did not specify any dependency restrictions. As I sort of hinted at there are other fine answers available if this route is not appropriate

Comment: I know, I don't think your answer is bad, but it wasn't made clear from your post that it required a huge third-party dependency.

Comment: This answer should be raised as the best one. Very simple and clean! Really outstanding!

Answer (score 6):

Your solution is slow because its complexity is `O(nm)` with `m` being the number of unique elements in `l`: `a.index()` is `O(m)` and you call it for every element in `l`.

To make it `O(n)`, get rid of `index()` and store indexes in a dictionary:

```
>>> idx, indexes = 1, {}
>>> for x in l:
...     if x not in indexes:
...         indexes[x] = idx
...         idx += 1
... 
>>> [indexes[x] for x in l]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

If `l` contains only integers in a known range, you could also store indexes in a list instead of a dictionary for faster lookups.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.OrderedDict()` in order to preserve the unique items in order and, loop over the enumerate of this ordered unique items in order to get a dict of items and those indices (based on their order) then pass this dictionary with the main list to `operator.itemgetter()` to get the corresponding index for each item:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> itemgetter(*lst)({j:i for i,j in enumerate(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst),1)})
(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Hint for readers: this approach uses `OrderedDict` as set preserving order.

Answer (score 1):

For completness, you can also do it eagerly:

> ```
> from itertools import count
>
> wordid = dict(zip(set(list_), count(1)))
> ```
>
> This uses a set to obtain the unique words in `list_`, pairs
>   each of those unique words with the next value from `count()` (which
>   counts upwards), and constructs a dictionary from the results.

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33504153/3821804), written by nneonneo.

Comment: Sets are unordered, so the indexes may not be assigned in the right order.